# Django templates - I want to render newline as \n instead of <br>

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm generating an XML file using Django template language and I came across a problem with linebreaks.

I'm trying to render `textarea` but I need to keep newlines - `\n` because the facebook catalogue feed accepts only `\n` as a newline.

I can't figure out how to make it work. `linebreaks` filter doesn't work.

Also `|safe` doesn't seem to work.

```
<description><![CDATA[{{ object.description|safe|truncatechars:5000 }}]]></description>
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Your description is conflicting with your title. Does Django render <br/> or do you want it to render <br/>? Or convert newlines to the string `\n`.

Comment: @Melvyn Thank you it's fixed